# Mediawiki can't display images or styles

Tags: image, apache, permissions, mediawiki

I`m using MediaWiki v1.19.1.

My wiki works well when I use it locally.
But when I access it over the network (from another computer, or a different IP),
it displays the text only. There are no images.

It seems like a classic skin but it`s not.
The reason is that there is no layout on my wiki (other public wiki pages show ok).

My wiki uses the monobook skin now, but I can see only the text on the page.

I have changed the permission to 777, including on all directories (`/var/www/kj/*`),
but still no images.

Help me, please...

Answer (score 3):

There's not enough information to give a definite answer, however general recommendations for such situations are:

- If you're using any Apache rewrite rules (for example, to [make URLs prettier](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL)), try disabling them.
- - Especially if you're using the `http://example.com/Page_title` style URLs, you should know that they're unsupported by the developers and require serious MediaWiki/Apache skills (and even then they will likely introduce subtle bugs).
- Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check what's the HTTP error for your images: is it because access is denied (HTTP 403) or the webserver doesn't see them at all (HTTP 404) - this should give you an idea what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue some time ago and the following worked fine for me.
The issue might be related to the **LocalSettings.php** file and the general setting **$wgServer**.

The following link can provide you more details : [Manual of $wgServer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgServer)

Since 1.18 MediaWiki has also supported setting **$wgServer** to a protocol-relative URL.

eg, *//www.mediawiki.org*

This is used for supporting both HTTP and HTTPS with the same caches by using links that work under both protocols.

So try removing **localhost** and provide your URL; eg ; **$wgServer = "//mywebsite.com";**