# Mediawiki page is not appearing properly

Tags: apache, xampp, mediawiki

I am facing an unique issue (possibly) on my Local Mediawiki. It's been installed on Windows XP (XAMPP server, Mediawiki 1.19.1). I have installed this as a - private wiki and added few stable extensions (like Cite, TitleKey etc.).

The problem is this wiki shows properly in my pc (localhost server) using the default **vector** skin but other cant view it properly. The page style/format is not appearing at all. I have tried to use **monobook** skin but that didnt help. Neither I am using short URL (as mentioned in the attached link) nor I have done much changes in LocalSettings.php. I am attaching a snap for more clarity. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218873/mediawiki-cant-display-images-or-styles)

[Image Snapshot](http://flic.kr/p/cY8HSs)

Comment: Can anybody help please? I am stuck :(

Comment: Check in the HTML source what location your CSS files are loaded from.

Comment: @Tgr Thanks for replying. Can you please put some more info i.e. in which HTML file I need to check which CSS? Being a novice pardon me.

Comment: The HTML page which is not appearing properly.

Comment: Thanks again @Tgr. Are you referring this -

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/piperwiki/load.php?debug=false&amp;lang=en-gb&amp;modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cskins.vector&amp;only=styles&amp;skin=vector&amp;*" />

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. It should start with `http://localhost` or `//localhost` or something like that. Your domain name must be misconfigured, check `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr :)
It worked after I changed the `$wgServer` in `LocalSettings.php` from `localhost` to `Static IP`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It worked after I changed the `$wgServer` in `LocalSettings.php` from `localhost` to machine Static `IP`. Possibly the domain name was misconfigured [as suggested by @Tgr]

Comment: In my case I had already had the FQDN of the server in $wgServer but had the incorrect protocol (I was redirecting to HTTPS and was missing the "s").